# Get all the parents of an id

Tags: sql, oracle

I have made a request, that should return all the `id`s and those parent's `id`s till the high of the tree like this :

```
SELECT co.id 
 from t_factory co 
start with co.id in (21,36) 
CONNECT BY PRIOR co.id = co.id_parent
```

So here, the values in `in()`are applies programmatically (no problem for this).

The parent is in the column id_parent for example I have the line :

```
id   id_parent
-----------
36   20
20   31
31   52
```

But, I read that the `start with`, and the `connect by prior` have to allow me to get all parents of the id's in `in (21,36)`

But it only return 21 and 36, while it should also return parent values  like this : 36, 20, 31, 52. Am I right?

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try another direction: `PRIOR co_parent.id = co.id` instead of `PRIOR co.id = co.id_parent`

```
SELECT co.id 
from t_factory co 
start with co.id in (21,36) 
CONNECT BY PRIOR co.id_parent = co.id
```

Comment: Well this works. Thank you. Can I have some explanationx? Is this a rule ? `PRIOR parent = child`?

Comment: I have made a SQLFiddle of this question and @schurik's answer: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3a58b/4

Comment: @Zaphod: that's called [hierarchical queries](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/queries003.htm)

Comment: Thank you for the link. Then, the `PRIOR`keyword MUST be in the parent side.

Comment: @Zaphod you start with co.id = 36 and  with the prior co.id_parent  you say that oracle must search for the next row where the id = the  id_parent of the current row. If you say prior id = id_parant, then  oracle search for the next row where id_parent = current id.